# Key authentication with ssl

Tags: tls, authentication

Can i authenticate myself in SSL with a key, just like in SSH?

Comment: Learn reading then. Or explain what exactly is poor.

Comment: Smit - despite the terseness of rook's comment, he has a good point. When you say 'just like in SSH' there are a number of things you could mean. It would help everyone if you list the authentication functionality that SSH gives you and you want from SSL.

Comment: I just don't want to enter password. This is all information i could give you. KK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) supports authentication of the client with an asymmetric key pair. Since this is SSL, it takes the form of a **client certificate**. The server requests a certificate during the initial handshake, indicating which root CA the server will use to validate that certificate; the client then sends a certificate to the server. This of course requires the client to actually *have* a certificate to send.

Usual clients (browsers) and servers support this feature. What the server does with the certificate is entirely up to it. In a Microsoft Active Directory + IIS world, the client certificate, once validated, is *mapped* to an account through one of several mechanisms (either the certificate itself is already attached to the account in the AD server, or the account name is found as a "User Principal Name" in the client certificate).

@Rook talks about [TLS with SRP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054), which is something completely different: with SRP, client and certificate authenticate *each other* with a *shared* secret (a password). There is no certificate anymore, not in the client and neither in the server. This has no equivalent in SSH (there was a patch to SSH for that, but it is not much maintained; it does not map well to account names and authentication as they are usually managed in operating systems). Usual SSL clients and server do not support SRP (but this may come in the future).

Comment: Is it possible to make them self signed?

Comment: As far as SSL is concerned, the certificates can be self-signed. It is up to the server to decide which certificate is acceptable or not. Self-signed client certificates closely emulate SSH key-based authentication.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, you can indeed use self-signed client certs (although I'd still verify the server cert the traditional PKI way), but this may [require a bit of tweaking](http://serverfault.com/a/382018/47187), since most frameworks expect a PKI model. In most cases, you may have to implement your own trust evaluation with the SSL/TLS stack, or disable it and do it within your application. Make sure your customisations eventually perform some form of verification (e.g. against a fixed list of public keys) before considering the client to be authenticated, from the application's point of view.